# How to count all data frame column values based on condition and transpose the columns into rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, aggregate-functions

Please find sample data in the Python dataframe as below. I have around 30 columns.

```
Column1  Column2  Column3
Male     Male     Female
Male     Female   Female
Female   Male     Female
Female   Male     Male
```

I want the output in the below format

```
            Male         Female
Column1     2              2
Column2     3              1
Column3     1              3
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me to achieve this in Python.

Thanks,
Sri.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Grouping and counting are covered in any PANDAS tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.melt().value_counts().unstack()

value     Female  Male
variable              
Column1        2     2
Column2        1     3
Column3        3     1
```

Get rid of axis names

```
df.melt().value_counts().rename_axis([None, None]).unstack()

         Female  Male
Column1       2     2
Column2       1     3
Column3       3     1
```

Answer (score 1):

`value_counts` in `apply` and `transpose`

```
df.apply(lambda c : c.value_counts()).transpose()
```

output

```
    Female  Male
Column1 2   2
Column2 1   3
Column3 3   1
```

Comment: PlusOne from me.

Comment: @piRSquared appreciate! but I like yours better